# How to show multiple doughnut chart in aura:iteration (In loop)

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, canvas, chart.js

Basically I want to show doughnut chart in aura iteration using a single Canvas, so that I can show multiple doughnut chart for one parent record.

Is there any way to set data for doughnut chart in iteration?

Component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.ParentRecord}" var="pa" indexVar="key">
    <span style = "float : center;">
        <canvas aura:id="chart" height="50" width="50">
    </canvas>
   </span>
</aura:iteration>
```

Here I need to set value of canvas for each record which in turns return one doughnut chart.
Here the chart I'm using is chart.js

Usually we set data of doughnut chart like below:
Controller

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    }]

var options = { responsive: true };

var element = component.find('chart').getElement();
var ctx = element.getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);
```